# PayPal Customers are charged even after Subscriptions are Cancelled (screenshot included)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

in the past few weeks we have seen our customers be charged AFTER they have cancelled their subscription in PayPal.

**Example:**

- Customer goes to our website and adds subscription with 30 day trial
  to cart.
- Customer is redirected to PayPal for authorization.
- Customer is redirected back to our website.
- ...10 days pass...
- Customer cancels their subscription/trial
- ...30 day trial ends...
- Customer is charged even though the subscription/trial is cancelled

**Actual Example:**

Customer cancels subscription on January 17 but is still charged February 16. See screenshot:

[image: paypalerror]

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: You may want to get some help from PayPal technical support https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/utils/login_form?p_next_page=ask with the subscription details provided. It's seems not something with your code, and worth looking into the PayPal system.

Comment: @pp_pduan that link seems to be broken, do you have another link?

Comment: @pp_pduan ignore that, seems to be working now, sorry about that. thanks btw!